# Duality for quadratic programming.

Tags: duality-theorems, quadratic-programming

How to prove that the second optimization problem is the dual problem of the first problem. I tried to prove that using Lagrangian dual function.

First optimization problem:

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & x^TQx\\ \text{subject to} & \\
\qquad e^Tx = 1\\
\qquad \mu^Tx \ge R\\
\qquad x \ge 0\\
\qquad e = [1,1,...,1]^T
\end{array}$$

Second optimiztaion problem:

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & \mu^Tx\\ \text{subject to} & \\
\qquad  e^Tx = 1\\
\qquad x^TQx \le \sigma\\
\qquad x \ge 0\\
\qquad e = [1,1,...,1]^T
\end{array}$$

where Q is an n by n positive definite matrix.  $x \in R^n,\ \mu \in R^n$ . $\ x$ and $\mu$ are n dimensional column vectors.

I tried to solve this by using Lagrangian dual function:

$$
L(x,\lambda,\alpha,\beta) = x^TQx+\lambda(R-\mu^Tx)-\alpha^Tx+\beta(e^Tx-1)=x^TQx+(\beta e - \alpha - \lambda \mu)^T x + \lambda R - \beta\\
\frac{\partial{L(x,\lambda,\alpha,\beta)}}{\partial{x}}=2Qx+\beta e-\alpha-\lambda \mu = 0\\
x = \frac{1}{2}Q^{-1}(\alpha+\lambda \mu-\beta e)
$$

Suppose t = -x, substitute t for x and take maximize, then we have the dual problem:

$$
\max_{\lambda \ge 0,\alpha \ge 0,\beta }  -t^TQt+\lambda R - \beta\\
s.t. \quad t = \frac{1}{2}Q^{-1}(\beta e - \alpha - \lambda \mu)
$$
Then I don't know how to continue to tranform this problem into the form of the second optimization problem.

Comment: Use `$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & (objective)\\ \text{subject to} & (constraint)\end{array}$$` instead.

Comment: Why does this question have 2 downvotes ?